# Proper way of implementing full dark theme in Compose-only applications

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-dark-theme

I have a Compose-only application that gives users three options of theming:

- System
- Light
- Dark

The theme is changed in Activity's `onCreate()` method by passing `darkTheme` argument to my app's theme `Composable` function.

If `System` is selected *and* Android system supports `Dark mode` (Android 10+), everything works fine.

But if `Dark` is selected, the dark theme defined in Compose is applied, *however* the system navigation bar at the bottom stays white.

Then I went to the `res/values/themes.xml` file and it looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="Theme.ExampleApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

So, I assume that the system navigation bar stays white, because in Compose the default theme is `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar` and we can't control its color from Compose code.

This is not a big problem for Android 10+ devices, because they can simply select `System` option, and then manually turn on/off the system `Dark mode` from within the Android.

But for the devices that don't support the system `Dark mode`, they navigation bar stays white, which looks terrible.

So, I did some searching and found a way to "fix" this (mainly from this [article](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme)).

1. First, I changed the parent theme in `styles.xml` file to the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="Theme.ExampleApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" />
</resources>
```

2. This doesn't work unless your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`. Default Compose-only applications have their activity extend `ComponentActivity`. So:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

3. Then I switch to so-called "Night mode" using the following functions:

```kotlin
// For SDK <= 30
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()

// For SDK >= 31
uiManager.setApplicationNightMode()
```

And it works!

However, I have some concerns and questions regarding this method.

1. Is it OK to use the `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` style for Compose-only application? It seems really old and I wonder if it breaks something in Compose.
2. What are the drawbacks of using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ComponentActivity` in Compose-only applications? I don't use `Fragment`s, so I don't really need it, but maybe again, it breaks something in Compose? Does it increase .apk size?
3. I don't know which parameters to call the functions `setDefaultNightMode()` and `setApplicationNightMode()` with for "Follow the system theme" mode. For the first one there is `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`, but the second function doesn't have it, and only has `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` and `MODE_NIGHT_CUSTOM`. They both say that they switch to "Night mode" based on the current time, which I don't really want. For Android 10+ I don't want them to break their native `Dark mode` functionality.

Comment: Good questions, did you find answers?

Answer (score 0):

If system status or navigation bars are not changing with in-app set theme, make sure to:

1. Remove properties like `android:windowLightStatusBar` and `android:windowLightNavigationBar` from `themes.xml`.
2. Set `isAppearanceLightStatusBars` and `isAppearanceLightNavigationBars` on `WindowInsetsControllerCompat` in your Compose theme.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
   useDarkTheme: Boolean =  isSystemInDarkTheme(),
   content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
 
 // color scheme selection code

 // Add primary status bar color from chosen color scheme.
 val view = LocalView.current
 if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = colors.primary.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).apply {
            isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !isDarkTheme
            isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !isDarkTheme
        }
    }
 }
   
 MaterialTheme(
   colorScheme = colors,
    content = content
 )
}
```